# ISOGG Y-DNA Haplogroup Tree download

Tags: dna, haplogroup, y-dna

On isogg website (http://isogg.org/tree/ISOGG_YDNATreeTrunk.html) I only found the html-based version of a Y-dna tree, that is not very easy to use. I want to download in to my personal computer and process it using some self-written scripts.

Are there any direct ways to download ISOGG Y-DNA Haplogroup Tree 2015 in some text format or there are some licence limitation?

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe they provided a download mechanism. The tree is hierarchical, and html with hyperlinks to lower levels with color coding was an efficient way for ISOGG to create and maintain the information. They are continuously updating it with new information and maintain [a yearly snapshot of the tree](http://www.isogg.org/tree/index.html), so they may not want people downloading copies that will quickly become out of date.

If you still want to download it, there are two possibilities:

1. Contact Ray Banks, who is the contact person for the ISOGG Y-DNA Haplogroup Tree. The link to contact him is displayed prominently on all the ISOGG Y-DNA Tree pages, so he wants to be contacted. Tell him what you are trying to do, and he may give you ulterior suggestions or maybe he'll just tell you how you can download the entire tree.
2. Try using Felix Immanuel's [ISOGG Y-Tree AddOn for Google Chrome](http://www.y-str.org/2014/04/isogg-y-tree-addon-for-google-chrome.html). Maybe that will do what you need. If not, (and you sound like a programming type of guy if you plan to write scripts) check out [his JavaScript source code for that Addon at Github](https://github.com/fiidau/ISOGG-YTree-AddOn-for-Google-Chrome). His program is accessing that data, so you might be able to modify it to produce your own extract of the ISOGG data. Or you could contact Felix Immanuel directly. He might be interested in writing something that will do what you want if he deems it useful.